# Bootstrap datetimepicker- Uncaught TypeError : Cannot to read property "getTime" of undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Uncaught TypeError : Cannot to read property "getTime" of undefined
You can find the error log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVZW0.png).

```
$('.modal-body').on("focus","#date",function() {
    var date = $('#date').val();
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: date,
        language: 'zh-CN',
        pickDate: true,
        pickTime: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayBtn: true,
        minView: 2,
        startView: 3,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
    });
);
```

Inserted into the pop-up window

```
$('#edit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{:U('SystemSettingMgt/settingConf')}",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'id' : $(this).siblings('input').val(),
            'is_active' : 1,
        },
        success:function(json){
            $('.modal-body').children().empty();
            var str = '';
            switch(json.datatype){
                // yes/false
                case "1":
                    str += '<label>select setting</label>';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="id" value="'+json.id+'">';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="datatype" value="'+json.datatype+'">';
                    str += '<select name="value" id="value" class="form-control">';
                    if (json.value == 1) {
                        str += '<option value="1" selected>yes</option>';
                        str += '<option value="0"false</option>';
                    }else if(json.value == 0){
                        str += '<option value="1">yes</option>';
                        str += '<option value="0" selected>false</option>';
                    }
                    str += '</select>';
                    $('.modal-body').children().append(str);
                    break;

                // enter string
                case "2":
                    str += '<label>enter setting</label>';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="id" value="'+json.id+'">';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="datatype" value="'+json.datatype+'">';
                    str += '<input name="value" id="value" class="form-control" value="'+json.value+'">';
                    $('.modal-body').children().append(str);
                    break;

                // enter num
                case "3":
                    str += '<label>select setting</label>';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="id" value="'+json.id+'">';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="datatype" value="'+json.datatype+'">';
                    str += '<input type="text" id="value" value="'+json.value+'" name="value" class="form-control" placeholder="设定值"  onkeyup="if(! /^\d+$/.test(this.value)){this.placeholder='+'只能整数'+';this.value='+';}">';
                    $('.modal-body').children().append(str);
                    break;

                // select date
                case "4":
                    str += '<label>select setting</label>';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="id" value="'+json.id+'">';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="datatype" value="'+json.datatype+'">';
                    str += '<input type="text" id="date" name="value" class="form-control date" placeholder="select date" value="'+json.value+'">';
                    $('.modal-body').children().append(str);
                    break;

                // date
                case "5":
                    str += '<label>change setting</label>';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="id" value="'+json.id+'">';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="datatype" value="'+json.datatype+'">';
                    str += '<input type="text" data-date-format="hh:ii" id="time" name="value" class="form-control date" placeholder="select time" value="'+json.value+'">';
                    $('.modal-body').children().append(str);
                    break;

                // select
                case "6":
                    str += '<label>change setting</label>';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="id" value="'+json.id+'">';
                    str += '<input type="hidden" id="datatype" value="'+json.datatype+'">';
                    str += '<select name="datasource"  id="value" class="form-control">';
                    for(i = 0; i < json.datasource.length; i++){
                        str += '<option value="'+i+'">'+json.datasource[i]+'</option>';
                    }
                    str += '</select>';
                    $('.modal-body').children().append(str);
                    break;
               }
         }
    });
    $('#editSetting').modal('show');
});
```

I guess the time format is the problem, but through the jQuery value will be given after the error.

Comment: Please share your code fiddle

Answer (score 5):

In bootstrap-datetimepicker.js is:

```
getDate: function () {
      var d = this.getUTCDate();
      if (d === null) {
        return null;
      }
      return new Date(d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    },
```

but when is set value of input  for example: 12:15 then d is undefined. You can override getUTCDate function in your code or change if to:

```
d === null || typeof d  ==='undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "getTime" of undefined

This error thrown when you haven't included the jQuery UI plugin.
Make sure you include it before any other scripts in your project except after the jQuery plugin.

Comment: But on other pages, the same code is ok. I guess it was jquery conflict, but also rejected

Comment: Even though, the same code is ok in the other pages, for this page the hierarchy of the jQuery calls to the jQuery library may be different. So its possible that the same code fails in this page because of the order of the jQuery library imports.

Comment: I found the problem, is the time format of the problem, with json.value plus go, but will be given, I now need to solve the problem of time format